# Deriving Feynman rules for scalar QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, interactions

I am a bit confused about Matthew D. Schwartz's statement of the Feynman rules in scalar QED (chapter 9, section 9.2 titled *Feynman rules for scalar QED*. The Lagrangian is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F^2_{\mu\nu} -\phi^\star(\Box + m^2)\phi - i eA_\mu[\phi^\star(\partial_\mu\phi)-(\partial_\mu\phi^\star)\phi] + e^2 A^2_\mu|\phi|^2 \tag{9.11}.
\end{equation}
For clarity I am posting a screenshot of the equations that are concerned

[image]

I don't understand how he writes that $\phi^\star(\partial_\mu\phi)$ annihilates the $e^{-}$ because I would think that the presence of $\phi$ in the other term $\phi(\partial_\mu\phi^\star)$ could also annihilate an electron. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying that the $\phi$ in the term $\phi (\partial_{\mu} \phi^*)$ can also annihilate an electron, in fact otherwise the term $\phi (\partial_{\mu} \phi^*)$ would not contribute to the Feynman rule of the vertex.

The two term in the Lagrangian provide two separate contributions. For example consider $\phi^* (\partial_{\mu} \phi )$ alone. We have that

1. $\phi^*$ must create the outgoing electron.
2. $\phi$ must annihilate the incoming electron.
3. $\partial_{\mu}$ acts on $\phi$ and spits out a term $-p^1_{\mu}$.

The term term $\phi (\partial_{\mu} \phi^*)$ will operate similarly and that is why the final Feynman rule has two different contributions.